# Typescript for Firebase Cloud Functions: Why do I get a build error, when functions folder in angular project but not when isolated in own project?

Tags: typescript, firebase, build, google-cloud-functions

For some reason `firebase deploy --only functions` includes `node_modules` of the outer webapp project, see the following output:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /Users/username/data/projects/projectname/webapp/prp-cli/functions
> tsc

../node_modules/@types/jspdf/index.d.ts(186,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
```

Note that jsPdf is not a dependency of the functions, but rather of the webapp containing the `functions` folder.

When isolating the functions folder into a separate projects the build / deploy of the functions works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't share a node_modules folder between both hosting and functions.  As you've discovered, they should be separate node projects.

In addition, node_modules isn't deployed when you run `firebase deploy --only functions`.  In fact, fully materialized node_modules isn't currently supported.  Instead, Cloud Functions will look at the package.json (package-lock.json) in your functions project, and effectively perform `npm install` to assemble all the dependencies listed in it.